# Why does this collision not work properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, game-physics

I am coding a basic ping pong game in python.

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *   
from tkinter.ttk import *
from math import sqrt  
import time, random

# creates tkinter window or root window   
Window = Tk()  
HEIGHT = 700  
WIDTH = 700  
c = Canvas(Window, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)  
c.pack()   
c.configure(bg='black')  


#Define mid x and y  

MID_X = WIDTH / 2  

MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2  

#Create paddles and ball   
paddle_1 = c.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 20, fill='grey', outline = 'white')    
paddle_2 = c.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 20, fill='grey', outline = 'white')   
ball = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill='white', outline = 'grey')
c.move(paddle_1, 300, 0)
c.move(paddle_2, 300, 680)  
c.move(ball, 330, 340)  
id = [paddle_1, paddle_2, ball]
ball_move_x = 0
ball_move_y = 10
cooldown = 0

#get co-ordinates of object  
def get_coords(i):  
    pos = c.coords(i) 
    x = int(pos[0] + pos[2]/2)  
    y = int(pos[1] + pos[3]/2)
    return x, y

#Bounce (makes goofy physics)
def bounce(x, y):
    x += random.randint(1,20)/10
    x *= -1
    y += 1
    y *= -1
    return x, y

#Collision code (uses co-ords and checks if within a certain range)  
def collision(paddle_x, paddle_y, ball_x, ball_y, x = ball_move_x, y = ball_move_y,):  
    if(ball_x in range(paddle_x-50, paddle_x+50, 1) and ball_y in range(paddle_y-30, paddle_y+30, 1)):
        x, y = bounce(ball_move_x, ball_move_y)
        print("collision")
        return x, y
    else:
        return x, y

# Optimised movement functions without cycling through with an if operator  
def move_paddle_1_left(e):
    c.move(paddle_1, -100, 0)  
def move_paddle_1_right(e):  
    c.move(paddle_1, +100, 0)  
def move_paddle_2_left(e):  
    c.move(paddle_2, -100, 0)  
def move_paddle_2_right(e):  
    c.move(paddle_2, +100, 0) 
 
# bind functions to key   
c.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>', move_paddle_1_left)  
c.bind_all('<KeyPress-d>', move_paddle_1_right)   
c.bind_all('<Left>', move_paddle_2_left)   
c.bind_all('<Right>', move_paddle_2_right)   
c.pack()   
#MAIN GAME LOOP  
while True:  
    Window.update()
    paddle_1_x, paddle_1_y = get_coords(id[0])  
    paddle_2_x, paddle_2_y = get_coords(id[1])  
    ball_x, ball_y = get_coords(id[2]) 
    ball_move_x, ball_move_y = collision(paddle_1_x, paddle_1_y, ball_x, ball_y)
    ball_move_x, ball_move_y = collision(paddle_2_x, paddle_2_y, ball_x, ball_y)
    c.move(ball, +ball_move_x, +ball_move_y)
    time.sleep(0.0333333)  
    Window.update()
```

The problem is that the collision (so far, only bouncing off paddles is implemented) is buggy: it will essentially collide and collide infinitely.

My approach to collision detection and response is that I get the balls middle co-ords and the bat's middle co-ords; if the ball's co-ords are within a range of the bats co-ords I count it as a collision.

Since then I have been having an issue where essentially it will collide infinitely and just spam up and down. Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Your level of experience is not relevant to the question; people do not need to be told to explain things clearly or to "dumb it down", because good answers do that anyway. I [edit]ed the question to remove such commentary, keep things organized and ask the question clearly.

Comment: What did you try so far to debug this? Stepping though the code line-by-line in a debugger? Writing out your logic on paper, or otherwise, and seeing if your design works in theory? I'd think if you did both of those, it'd be very unlikely you'd still need help. Or, you could at least understand exactly where the confusion lies. Right now you just have a bunch of code (a lot of which is not relevant - this should be a [mre]), and a statement kinda explaining the symptoms of the problem, but there's not really any conjecture by you as to the nature of the issue.

Comment: That said, there is more that we need from you to be able to answer this properly. Being new or unskilled does not relieve you of the burden of [trying to figure things out yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) or [studying things you don't understand yet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). In fact, it makes those things *more* important, since those are the primary ways of learning and improving.

Comment: as for me you don't bounce but you always move in the same direction so it collides with paddle all time. But after collsion you should change direction. You could use variable which keep direction `down` or `up` and it uses it to `add` or `substract` value to position. And when you collide then you should change from `down` to `up`, or from `up` to `down`. OR you should use variable `speed` which you will add to position and it detect collision then change `speed = -speed` and it will move in other direction.

Comment: now I see - when you detect collision then you run `bounce` which use `x *= -1` to change direction and it make move `up` - but in next move it uses original `x` and it moves again `down`. You should keep global variable ie. `direction = +1` and every move do `x *= direction` (not only when you detect collision) and when you detect collision then set `direction = -direection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you detect collision then you use `x *= -1` to move in different direction (`up`) but in next moves you don't use `-1` to keep the same direction and it move again down.

You should keep this value as global variable

```
direction_x = 1
direction_y = 1
```

and alwasy use

```
return x*direction_x, y*direction_y
```

And when you detect collision then change direction

```
direction_y = -direction_y
```

```
direction_x = 1
direction_y = 1


def collision(paddle_x, paddle_y, ball_x, ball_y, x = ball_move_x, y = ball_move_y,):  
    global direction_x
    global direction_y
    
    if (paddle_x-50 <= ball_x <= paddle_x+50) and (paddle_y-30 <= ball_y <= paddle_y+30):
        direction_y = - direction_y
        print("collision")
        
    return x*direction_x, y*direction_y
```

---

Full working code with other changes

**EDIT:**

You forgot `()` when you calculate center - you have to first add and later divide but without `()` it first divided and later added.

```
    x = int((pos[0] + pos[2])/2)  
    y = int((pos[1] + pos[3])/2)
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from math import sqrt  
import time
import random

# --- constants ---

HEIGHT = 700  
WIDTH  = 700  

MID_X = WIDTH / 2  
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2  

BALL_MOVE_X = 0
BALL_MOVE_Y = 10

# --- functions ---

def get_coords(canvas, item):  
    pos = canvas.coords(item) 
    x = int( (pos[0] + pos[2]) / 2 )  
    y = int( (pos[1] + pos[3]) / 2 )
    return x, y

def collision(paddle_x, paddle_y, ball_x, ball_y, x=BALL_MOVE_X, y=BALL_MOVE_Y):  
    global direction_x
    global direction_y
    
    if (paddle_x-50 <= ball_x <= paddle_x+50) and (paddle_y-30 <= ball_y <= paddle_y+30):
        direction_y = - direction_y
        print("paddle collision")
        
    return x*direction_x, y*direction_y

def move_paddle_1_left(e):
    canvas.move(paddle_1, -100, 0)
    
def move_paddle_1_right(e):  
    canvas.move(paddle_1, +100, 0)
    
def move_paddle_2_left(e):  
    canvas.move(paddle_2, -100, 0)
    
def move_paddle_2_right(e):  
    canvas.move(paddle_2, +100, 0) 

def gameloop():
    # MAIN GAME LOOP  

    paddle_1_x, paddle_1_y = get_coords(canvas, paddle_1)  
    paddle_2_x, paddle_2_y = get_coords(canvas, paddle_2)
    
    ball_x, ball_y = get_coords(canvas, ball)
    
    ball_move_x, ball_move_y = collision(paddle_1_x, paddle_1_y, ball_x, ball_y)
    ball_move_x, ball_move_y = collision(paddle_2_x, paddle_2_y, ball_x, ball_y)
    canvas.move(ball, ball_move_x, ball_move_y)

    window.after(25, gameloop)  # repeat after 25ms
    
# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()    # PEP8: `lower case name`

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='black')  # PEP8: `=` without spaces inside `( )`
canvas.pack()   

paddle_1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 20, fill='grey', outline='white')    
paddle_2 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 20, fill='grey', outline='white')   
canvas.move(paddle_1, 300, 0)
canvas.move(paddle_2, 300, 680)  

ball = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill='white', outline='grey')
canvas.move(ball, 330, 340)  

ball_move_x = 0
ball_move_y = 10

direction_x = 1
direction_y = 1

cooldown = 0
 
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>', move_paddle_1_left)  
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-d>', move_paddle_1_right)   
canvas.bind_all('<Left>', move_paddle_2_left)   
canvas.bind_all('<Right>', move_paddle_2_right)   

window.after(25, gameloop)  # 25ms = 0.025s = 40 Frames Per Second (FPS)

window.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

Version which change direction when touch window's border

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from math import sqrt  
import time
import random

# --- constants ---

HEIGHT = 700  
WIDTH  = 700  

MID_X = WIDTH / 2  
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2  

BALL_MOVE_X = 5
BALL_MOVE_Y = 10

# --- functions ---

def get_coords(canvas, item):  
    pos = canvas.coords(item) 
    x = int((pos[0] + pos[2])/2)  
    y = int((pos[1] + pos[3])/2)
    return x, y

def collision(paddle_x, paddle_y, ball_x, ball_y, x=BALL_MOVE_X, y=BALL_MOVE_Y):  
    global direction_x
    global direction_y
    
    if (paddle_x-50 <= ball_x <= paddle_x+50) and (paddle_y-30 <= ball_y <= paddle_y+30):
        direction_y = - direction_y
        print("paddle collision")
        #return x, y
    
    return x, y

def move_paddle_1_left(e):
    canvas.move(paddle_1, -100, 0)
    
def move_paddle_1_right(e):  
    canvas.move(paddle_1, +100, 0)
    
def move_paddle_2_left(e):  
    canvas.move(paddle_2, -100, 0)
    
def move_paddle_2_right(e):  
    canvas.move(paddle_2, +100, 0) 

def gameloop():
    # MAIN GAME LOOP  
    global direction_x
    global direction_y
 
    paddle_1_x, paddle_1_y = get_coords(canvas, paddle_1)  
    paddle_2_x, paddle_2_y = get_coords(canvas, paddle_2)
    
    ball_x, ball_y = get_coords(canvas, ball)

    if ball_x <= 0 or ball_x >= WIDTH:
        direction_x = - direction_x

    if ball_y <= 0 or ball_y >= HEIGHT:
        print("Get point")        
        direction_y = - direction_y
        
    ball_move_x, ball_move_y = collision(paddle_1_x, paddle_1_y, ball_x, ball_y)
    ball_move_x, ball_move_y = collision(paddle_2_x, paddle_2_y, ball_x, ball_y)
        
    canvas.move(ball, ball_move_x*direction_x, ball_move_y*direction_y)

    window.after(25, gameloop)  # repeat after 25ms
    
# --- main ---


window = tk.Tk()    # PEP8: `lower case name`

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='black')  # PEP8: `=` without spaces inside `( )`
canvas.pack()   

paddle_1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 20, fill='grey', outline='white')    
paddle_2 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 20, fill='grey', outline='white')   
canvas.move(paddle_1, 300, 0)
canvas.move(paddle_2, 300, 680)  

ball = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, fill='white', outline='grey')
canvas.move(ball, 330, 340)  

ball_move_x = 0
ball_move_y = 10

direction_x = 1
direction_y = 1

cooldown = 0
 
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>', move_paddle_1_left)  
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-d>', move_paddle_1_right)   
canvas.bind_all('<Left>', move_paddle_2_left)   
canvas.bind_all('<Right>', move_paddle_2_right)   

window.after(25, gameloop)  # 25ms = 0.025s = 40 Frames Per Second (FPS)

window.mainloop()
```